# Angular model fails to update after select option is filtered out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-ng-options

Trying to figure out why the model does not update when the bound selected option no longer exists. I would expect the model's property to update to undefined/null/empty string.

**Situation:** One `select` drives another `select` using filter. After selections are made, go to the original `select` and choose another option. Filter will remove the second `select` option as expected, but the model property on the second `select` will be unchanged.

**Problem:** When you go to pass the model, it will be populated with bad/previous values. In addition, using Angular validation, the `select` being required...the form is technically "valid" because the model has a value (the previous value) for the property.

HTML:

```
<select name="Category" ng-model="selectedCategory" 
       ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in categories">
   <option value="">All Categories</option>
</select>

<select name="SubCategory" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" 
       ng-options="item.name as item.subCategory for item in categories | filter:selectedCategory">
  <option value="">All SubCategories</option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.categories = [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Truck",
      "subCategory": "Telescope"
   }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Truck",
      "subCategory": "Hazmat"
   }, {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Van",
      "subCategory": "Mini"
   }];
});
```

I'm fairly certain I could tie an ng-change function to the first  to force it to update the model, but is there a better way?

Example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SgtQBBfgaI6e4K2bH3i?p=preview) demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedCategory', function(selectedCategory){
    $scope.selectedSubCategory = null;
});
```

Comment: Yes this technically works, but adding a $watch to each tied select could become expensive, no? Is there a better/cleaner way?

Comment: Andrew, I think this is right solution for your case. 1 watcher for 1 select - it's OK

Comment: @Andrew Dickerson Your other option is as you outlined at the end of your question -- you can simply force the state of the selectedSubCategory to effectively nothing. 

`ng-change="selectedSubCategory = ''"`

Comment: @AndrewDickerson This use case is interesting in that AngularJS shows the value of the model as valid when the options are changed.
`<select name="SubCategory" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-options="item.subCategory as item.subCategory for item in categories | filter:selectedCategory" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="" class="">All SubCategories</option><option value="0">Mini</option></select>`  I think perhaps this is something that should be detected for in AngularCore, as the model should technically be `ng-invalid` since the model value no longer is an option.  Pull request?

Comment: @DavidSungLee This is what concerned me as well. I would not expect it to be valid with no value present.